# Локальный максимум в массиве Java

Tags: java

Задача:

> Из массива удалить локальные максимумы. (Локальный максимум — это элемент, который больше любого из его соседних элементов.)

Важно:

Размер данного массива гарантированно больше 1.
Данный массив гарантированно не равен null.
Если у массива нет локальных максимумов, то вы должны вернуть его копию без изменений.

Моё решение:

```java
public class Task1 {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0};
 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeLocalMax(array)));
    }
 
    public static int[] removeLocalMax(int[] array) {
 
        /*Создаю массив из чисел, которые не являются локальными максимумами. */
        List<Integer> locals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                if (array[0] < array[1]) {
                    locals.add(array[i]);
                }
            } else if (i < array.length - 1) {
                if (array[i] < array[i + 1] || array[i] < array[i - 1]) {
                    locals.add(array[i]);
                }
            } else if (i == array.length - 1) {
                if (array[i] < array[i - 1]) {
                    locals.add(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        /*Проверка если массив из одинаковых чисел, то просто перезаписать его*/
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array.length - 1) {
                if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {
                    locals.add(array[i]);
                }
            } else {
                if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
                    locals.add(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        /* Записываю результат в массив который возвращаю*/
        int[] arr = new int[locals.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < locals.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = locals.get(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }}
```

Результат моего кода:

Для стандартных массивов по типу: {10, 5, 9, 4} - всё работает правильно, но для массивов которые состоят из одинаковых чисел всё ломается.

Так же понимаю что мой код не из чистых, только учусь. Может будут решения логичнее)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лишнее убрал:

```
    List<Integer> locals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (array[0] <= array[1]) {
                locals.add(array[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        if (array[i] <= array[i + 1] || array[i] <= array[i - 1]) {
              locals.add(array[i]);
        }
    }
    if (array[array.length - 2] >= array[array.length - 1]) {
                locals.add(array[array.length - 1]);
    }

    int[] arr = new int[locals.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < locals.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = locals.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
```

Comment: предполагается, что мы еще не знаем Listы. А есть возможность использовать методы java.Utils.Arrays
можно это решить без листов, стримов и прочих плюшек?